# ERROR HANDLING for my String tokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

```
else if (sCarRental.equals("EP")) {
                sStationCode = st.nextToken().trim();
                sName=st.nextToken().trim();
                sLocationCode = st.nextToken().trim();
                sAddress1=st.nextToken().trim();
                sAddress2=st.nextToken().trim();
                sPostCode=st.nextToken().trim();
                sCity=st.nextToken().trim();
                sStationName=sName+sAddress1+sAddress2+sPostCode+sCity;
                sStationType="C";
                if(sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) 
                {
                    sStationArea="C";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="S";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="N";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="E";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="W";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="T";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="R";
                }
                else if (sLocationCode.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))   
                {
                    sStationArea="R";
                }
                else    
                {
                    sStationArea="C";
                }
                sSupplierCode ="EP";
                sLocationCode=sStationCode.substring(0, 3);
                sCrsCode = "EP";
            }
```

I want to read a csv file and write it to a database

But here i want to add some error handling .. So how can i do that ..normally my csv file should contain 7 values what if if there are only 4 values

help appreciated ..

Comment: @Umair StringTokenizer I think.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably could do something like this... create an API to return the value if exist, otherwise throw an exception:-

```
private String getValue(StringTokenizer st, String name) {
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        return st.nextToken().trim();
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing value for " + name);
    }
}
```

In your code, instead of calling `st.nextToken().trim()`, you call that API:-

```
else if (sCarRental.equals("EP")) {

    sStationCode = getValue(st, "station code");
    sName=getValue(st, "name");
    sLocationCode = getValue(st, "location code");
    sAddress1=getValue(st, "address 1");
    sAddress2=getValue(st, "address 2");
    sPostCode=getValue(st, "post code");
    sCity=getValue(st, "city ");

    ...
 }
```